# Trying to get table height = 100% in Chrome

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm trying to make a table that expands when clicked, so it starts off as one row, then two, then three etc, but stay at 100% height. This works fine in FF, IE and Opera, but when I added the third row in Chrome it now starts off as 50% opposed to 100%.

I've looked around for ages, and as it's for a revision plan for an exam in a few days I'm running out of time a bit haha.

So yeah, if anyone could offer any help that'd be super helpful and much appreciated.

(I guess I shouldn't post all my code, so I'll try shorten it to only the relevant bits without the style tags and what not- if anyone wants me to post the rest I can)

```
  function toggleSub() {
if( document.getElementById("hideSub").style.display=='none' ){
document.getElementById("hideSub").style.display = '';
}else{
document.getElementById("hideSub").style.display = 'none';
document.getElementById("hideNeuro").style.display = 'none';
document.getElementById("hideAtypicalBlank").style.display = 'none';
document.getElementById("hideAtypical").style.display = 'none';
}
}
function toggleNeuro() {
if( document.getElementById("hideNeuro").style.display=='none' ){
document.getElementById("hideNeuro").style.display = '';
document.getElementById("hideAtypicalBlank").style.display = 'none';
}else{
document.getElementById("hideNeuro").style.display = 'none';
if(document.getElementById("hideAtypical").style.display == '')
document.getElementById("hideAtypicalBlank").style.display = '';
}
}
function toggleAtypicalBlank() {
if( document.getElementById("hideAtypicalBlank").style.display=='none' && 
document.getElementById("hideNeuro").style.display=='none'){
document.getElementById("hideAtypicalBlank").style.display = '';
}else{
document.getElementById("hideAtypicalBlank").style.display = 'none';
}
}
function toggleAtypical() {
if( document.getElementById("hideAtypical").style.display=='none' ){
document.getElementById("hideAtypical").style.display = '';
}else{
document.getElementById("hideAtypical").style.display = 'none';
}
}


  table#table3{
  margin:0;
  padding:0;
  height:100%;
  border:none
}


<table border="1" id="table3" width="100%">
<tr>
    <th colspan="2"><span onClick="toggleSub();">Drug Therapy</span></th>
</tr>
<tr id="hideSub" style="display:none;" >
    <td width="50%"><span onClick="toggleNeuro();">Neuroleptics</span> </td>
    <td width="50%"><span onClick="toggleAtypical();toggleAtypicalBlank()">Atypical</span> </td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td id="hideNeuro" style="display:none;">blah blah blah </td>
    <td id="hideAtypicalBlank" style="display:none;"> </td>
    <td id="hideAtypical" style="display:none;">blah blah blah </td>
</tr>
```

Answer (score 1):

http://jsfiddle.net/mazlix/FLpFR/ works for me in both chrome and firefox, could you let me know if it gives you problems. Are you using the latest version of chrome?

Comment: Yeah I just updated Chrome and am still having the problem, and in the link, the table doesn't have 100% height for me in the 'result' box.

Comment: could explain what's wrong? when I use inspect element, it shows the table#table3 as having height=100%... what does yours say?, what does it look like?

Comment: The table is at 50% in Chrome at the start, and then later expands into 100% when you unhide the third row. I inspected the element and it says height = 100%, but it isn't... I took some pictures: http://imageshack.us/g/190/dsc1250i.jpg/ - The first one is how it looks in Firefox (and how it should look) whereas the other 3 show what happens in Chrome. I hope that better illustrates my problem.

Answer (score 1):

It seems that for Chrome, you need to make the table row `display:none` as well as the table cells.

At this [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/3EMaA/2/), I've set the third table row to `display:none` at start up, and added the function `updateRow3` to set the third row to `display:none` or not depending on whether any of its table cells are visible.

Comment: Thanks! I'll have to try this in the morning to just double check, but it works brilliantly in that link.

Comment: Hey, I just tried it out, and realised that it's fine going through, but when you collapse the first row it is at 50% again. This is true in the link too, I just didn't notice it last night

Comment: Ah, I see. Just add a call to `updateRow3` at the end of the `toggleSub` method. Updated jsfiddle is here: http://jsfiddle.net/3EMaA/3/

Comment: I thought it'd be something similar to that, but I had to rush to college so didn't have time to try. But still, thanks very much! I've been trying to sort this out since Sunday, so to finally sort it out is fantastic. If I wanted to add more rows, could I just add a modified `updateRow3` bit?

Comment: I expect so. It's just a case of applying the rule "if all cells for a row are hidden, then also hide the row itself, otherwise show the row."

Comment: Excellent, it's been a bit tricky to modify but I think I understand it now, so thank again.

Answer (score 0):

It seen that if you put a style in for the table row and give it a height of 100%, it will work. So another way to do this would be to give each table row a height in a percentage and then change the height respectively with your JS. I can post the code for this if you want.

Comment: Yeah I was trying to do something like this for ages, so if it isn't too much trouble could you post the code?

Comment: Even though the problem has been sorted, this would still be helpful for me if you wouldn't mind still posting the code

Comment: Here is a link to the code:   http://d.pr/TYmr    (It was a bit long to just post) I added borders so you can see exactly what's happening.